# Develiper profil: Provisioning Profiles

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, certificate, provisioning

I'm having a problem trying to test of the device

I know this subject has been gone over multiple times but I can't find an answer to the following question:

My company has a company dev license.

They directly generated a Provisioning certificate on the apple website so when I plug a device in and log on with my apple ID I get the provisioning certificate automatically but it then tells me :

"XCode could not find a valid private-key/certificate pair for this profile in your keychain".

What I think in happening is this :

since I didn't submit a request for a certificate to be approved by the team lead (as described [here](http://developer.apple.com/ios/manage/certificates/team/howto.action)), the certificate I get is not valid for my machine

If anybody has an alternate theory I can test please let me know (because otherwise I have to wait for my team lead to be available LOL)

Comment: I just had the same problem. Download the certificate - if you have access to it - and move it in your keychain - that should do it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct way would be to register yourself as a developer in your company account and then request a new certificate from apple website for yourself. Once you get that then edit the provisioning profile and add your name in it.

Other way around is to export certificate and key chain from person's machine who is registered as developer and import them in your machine. Certificate and key chain can be exported form key chain utility. then simply copy them to your machine and double lick will do.

Post here if you need more help.

Comment: FOund the problem, the guy who added my apple ID to the team profile must have added a key generated on his machine, and of course apple webiste doesn't allow you to edit anything lol so I had to reregister